# How to skip indexes?

Tags: python, list, skip

I am having an issue with last part of a code I'm creating. I am trying to, for example, make the list iterate to item 3 normally, but then check if the item is 3 and other condition (which doesn't matter right now), then change the index to iterate from example 10.

I made a lot of attempts but it doesn't seem to work.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for i in range(0,len(li)):
    print(i)
    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        def g(li):
            global i
            i = li[9]
        g()
        print(i)
```

Comment: Why use a nested function at all? Also, a Python `for` loop is different than a Java/C `for` loop; the value of `i` will be replaced, not modified, in the next iteration. Maybe use a `while` loop instead?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `continue` statement:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for i in range(len(li)):
    if 3 <= i < 10: #along with other condition
        continue
    print(i)
```

output when printing `i`:

> 0,1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15

output when printing `li[i]`:

> 1,2,3,11,12,13,14,15,16

the `continue` statement brings you at the beginning of the loop, ignoring all the following conditions.
you may want to have a look to the [loop control statements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop isn't necessary. If you're happy using a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(li)

res = A[np.r_[:4, 9:len(A)]]

# array([ 1,  2,  3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
```

Or with regular Python you can use `slice` objects:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

slices = (slice(0, 4), slice(9, None))

res = list(chain.from_iterable(itemgetter(*slices)(li)))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of i to some value inside your for loop.  At the beginning of each iteration of the for loop, python updates the value of i to be the next value in the iterable that it is iterating over.  Therefor, your value is lost and not used.

One solution would be to use another variable (skip_until) like so:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
skip_until = -1
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i == 3:
        skip_until = 9
    if skip_until >= i:
        continue      
    print((i, lst[i]))
```

output:

> (0, 1)
>   (1, 2)
>   (2, 3)
>   (10, 11)
>   (11, 12)
>   (12, 13)
>   (13, 14)
>   (14, 15)
>   (15, 16)

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
condition3_reached = False
condition10_reached = False
for i in li:
    print(i)
    if conditition3_reached and not condition10_reached and i != 10:
        continue
    if condition3_reached and i == 10:
        condition10_reached = True
    if i == 3 and (#along with other condition):
        condition3_reached = True
        print(i)
    else:
        do_some_new_thing_for_10_onwards()
```

this is a simple way of achieving what you want. My worry is that it is not scalable

Answer (score 0):

Should use continue like so:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for i in range(0,len(li)):
    if i in range(3, li[9]):
        continue
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and readable way to accomplish this is through the use of a `while` as opposed to the `for` loop as depicted below.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
i = 0
while i < len(li):
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        i = 10
        print(i)
    i += 1 # increment i at the end of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

i try to understand what you said and i wrote this code

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
def k(pos = 0):
    for i in li[pos:]:
        print(i)
        if li.index(i) == 3: #along with other condition
            return k(pos = 9)
k()
```

Comment: surely,you can change the pos and condition you want

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not really possible with a Python `for` loop, which is less than a Java/C style `for (initializer; step; condition)` loop, but more like a `foreach (iterable)` loop, where the iterable just happens to be a `range` in your case.

Thus, whenever you do `i = ...` in your loop (`i` being the variable from the `for` loop), `i` will be overwritten (not modified) with a new value in the next iteration of the loop.

Instead, you can use a slightly longer `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(li):
    print(i)
    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        def g(li):
            global i
            i = li[9]
        g(li)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Also note that the nested function `g` apparantly does not serve any purpose and can be removed, although the case may be different in your actual code.

```
i = 0
while i < len(li):
    print(i)
    if i == 3: #along with other condition
        i = li[9]
    else:
        i += 1
```